# Views exposed date filters

Tags: 7, datetime, views

Can anyone tell me how I can use 2 Views exposed filters to filter nodes published between the two selected dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Date Views module that comes shipped with [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date). Add a filter to your view using the Date: Date option.

[image: Date:Date]

Now you can use the "In Between" option to either select between two specific dates, or relative dates (within the past 30 days of right now). Make sure to check "Expose this filter to views".

[image: In Between Date Views]

[image: Live version with exposed dates.]

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'Content revision: Updated date' filter and another filter (not exposed) which is 'published' - true.

[image: Screenshot]